# Configuring Jetty 6 to use commons.dbcp datasource

Tags: java, jdbc, jetty, apache-commons

Hi I'm trying to configure Jetty 6.1.26 to use connection pooling and it's giving me a hard time.

I put `commons-dbcp-1.4.jar`, `commons-pool-1.5.6.jar` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.16` in 
my Jetty/lib/ext folder.

I also added references to those jars in my Jetty/pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
   ...
   <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.16</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In my web project in eclipse, my jetty-env.xml (in WEB-INF) file is like this:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

<New id="MySQLDB" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
<Arg>MySQLDB</Arg>
<Arg>
 <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <Set name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
    <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://host_ip</Set>
    <Set name="username">user</Set>
    <Set name="password">pwd</Set>
    <Set name="auth">Container</Set>
    <Set name="maxActive">-1</Set>
    <Set name="maxIdle">30</Set>
    <Set name="maxWait">10000</Set>
    <Set name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis">600000</Set>
    <Set name="name">MySQLDB</Set>
    <Set name="removeAbandoned">true</Set>
    <Set name="removeAbandonedTimeout">5000</Set>
    <Set name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis">10000</Set>
    <Set name="type">javax.sql.DataSource</Set>
 </New>
</Arg>
```

```
</Configure>
```

However, when I start Jetty (using `java -jar start.jar` in my Jetty directory), I get this exception:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.setAuth(class java.lang.String)`

How can I setup Jetty correctly?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have  <Set name="auth">Container</Set> the instruction says to call the method setAuth of the class. But the class doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: @Femi Oh, right. How dumb of me... It's working like a charm now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the lines `<Set name="auth">Container</Set>` and `<Set name="type">javax.sql.DataSource</Set>` from the configuration: the exception is telling you that those functions don't exist on the `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` class.